# arreglo de estrucutras

Tags: c, estructuras

quiero llenar una arreglo de estructuras **liga[20]** de **a** elementos pero no se que esta mal al llamarla en mi ciclo **for** y al pasarla por referencia, o no se si estoy hacienod bien el paso por referencia , ayuda por favor soy nuevo :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char nombre[20] ;
    int pJ , pG , pE , pP
}liga[ 20 ] ;

void lectura( liga *) ;

int main ( ) {
    int i , a;
    liga w[20];
    printf(" numero de equipos: ");
    scanf( " %d " , &a) ;
    for( i=0 ; i<=a ; i++ ) {
        lectura( &(w[i]) ) ;
    }
}

void lectura ( liga *x ) {
    printf("nombre del equipo: ");
    gets( &x->nombre ) ;
    printf( "\n partidos jugados: " );
    scanf( " %d " , &x->pJ ) ;
    printf( "\n partidos ganados: " );
    scanf( " %d " , &x->pG ) ;
    printf( "\n partidos empatados: " );
    scanf( " %d " , &x->pE ) ;
    printf( "\n partidos perdidos: " );
    scanf( " %d " , &x->pP ) ;
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías ser mas descriptivo con el error que tienes con tu programa, de favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Corregí un poco el código y te deje un for de prueba, espero te sirva

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct liga{
    char nombre[20] ;
    int pJ , pG , pE , pP;
}; /*Asi se declara un struct*/

void lectura(struct liga *x) ; /*Así se declara la estructura de un método, es decir, valor que regresa (void), nombre del método(Lectura),tipo de dato que espera recibir como referencia (struct liga), nombre de la variable que vas a pasar por referencia(esta la puedes escribir de la misma manera en la implementación ya del método, lo cual es lo recomendado, o puedes cambiarle el nombre)*/

int main ( ) {
    int i , a;
    struct liga w[20];/*Aquí se declara el arreglo del tipo struct con su propio nombre y el tamaño que tendrá*/
    printf(" numero de equipos: ");
    scanf( "%d" , &a) ;
    fflush(stdin);/*Este sirve para limpiar el scanf y que el los próximos scanf no se vayan a saltar o tomar por omisión un valor previo ingresado por consola*/
    for( i=0 ; i<a ; i++ ) {
        lectura( &(w[i]) ) ;
    }
    for( i=0 ; i<a ; i++ ) {
        printf("%s\n",w[i].nombre);/*Para acceder al valor de la variable dentro del struct se pone la posicion del arreglo que quieres entrar(i) y accedes con '.' y la variable de la cual quieres acceder al valor(nombre)*/
    }
}

void lectura (struct liga *x) {
    printf("nombre del equipo: ");
    scanf ("%s",x->nombre); /*En el caso de los arreglo de char no es necesario entrar por referencia*/
    printf( "\n partidos jugados: " );
    scanf( "%d" ,&x->pJ ) ;
    printf( "\n partidos ganados: " );
    scanf( "%d" ,&x->pG ) ;
    printf( "\n partidos empatados: " );
    scanf( "%d" ,&x->pE ) ;
    printf( "\n partidos perdidos: " );
    scanf( "%d" ,&x->pP ) ;
}
```

Comment: Listo, ya le agregué algunos comentarios.